# How to pass a parameter to a powershell script in a jenkins pipeline

Tags: powershell, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

How do I pass my variable VAR_A to an embedded powershell script in a jenkins pipeline ?

e.g.

```
def VAR_A = 'test'
def mystatus = powershell(returnStatus: true, script: '''
                Write-Host "My result: '$VAR_A'" '''


withEnv(["VAR_A=test"]) {
def mystatus = powershell(returnStatus: true, script: '''
                Write-Host "My result: '$VAR_A'" '''
}
```

both result with following output
My result: ''

Note : I prefer to define my powershell script in the jenkinsfile to keep things simple.

Comment: try this: def mystatus = powershell(returnStatus: true, script: """                Write-Host \"My result: \" $VAR_A""" . for env var use $env:VAR_A

Comment: this is correct : $env:VAR_A. thanks

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Try this:

```
node {
    powershell '''
        $VAR_A = 'test'
        Write-Host "My result: '$VAR_A'"
    '''
    withEnv(["VAR_A=envtest"]) {
        powershell '''
            Write-Host "My result is empty: '$VAR_A'"
            Write-Host "My env result: '$env:VAR_A'"
        '''
    }
}
```

The output is:

```
My result: 'test'

My result is empty: ''
My env result: 'envtest'
```

This was tested on Jenkins 2.73.1.

Note that:

- `$VAR_A = 'test'` is declared within the first `powershell '''...'''`
- `env:` is required to access environment variables (see [about_Environment_Variables](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_environment_variables) in the Microsoft Docs)

Comment: Also be aware that a space between variable name and equal sign is not supported! `withEnv(["VAR_A =envtest"])` doesn't work, where `withEnv(["VAR_A= envtest"]) ` works.